# Asus Laptop -- can't reformat

Tags: asus-laptop, reset

Last week I bought an Asus Laptop (Asus TUF F15: https://www.newegg.com/p/2WC-000N-03YF4?Item=9SIA7ABEDH5283). Long story short, it's defective and I need to return.

Before returning it, obviously, I want to reformat. However, the reformat process stops and does not continue.

## Process 1: standard Windows Reset option

I follow the prompts to reset the PC per normal:

[image]

When “Status: preparing” reaches 100%, the machine reboots:

[image]

After reboot, however, the system enters a screen where every option is an unhelpful deadend that halts the restore process:

[image]

Here's a video showing most of the options (some options aren't shown, but they are also dead ends):

https://streamable.com/llw20m

## Process 2: Windows boot media

Windows boot media says it is unable to detect any drives:

[image]

---

So, I'm stumped. Any other methods of reformatting a hard disk? It's an M.2 drive and I do not have an external M.2 drive reader.

Comment: Get / make a Linux boot disk and start with that. Can you see the drive?

Comment: Yes just booted Fedora and it can see the drive

Comment: Call ASUS Support and ask them how you can clear the drive.